# Symfony 2 rendering form error not associated with form field

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

Right now my errors theme looks like this:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block form_errors %}
    {% for child in form %}
        {% for error in child.vars.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger fade in margin-bottom-40">
                <h4>{{ child.vars.label|trans }}</h4>
                {{ error.message|trans }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```

and this is fine until I add error to the whole entity, not to particular field. My validator is doing something like this:

```
$this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
              ->addViolation();
```

Then the error message isn't shown, what is obvious.

**What I want to do** is to keep current schema of showing errors associated with fields and add something similar to errors for whole entity/form. Do You guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're adding putting the violation on the Entity itself, it will go on the root form so put something like:

```
{% for errors in form.vars.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger fade in margin-bottom-40">
      {{ error.message|trans }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

before rendering the errors for the form's children.

Comment: Actually, enough is just {% for error in errors %}, but Your answer is ok too :)